# Unexpected undefined returned as subscription from Observable, where object expected

Tags: javascript, observable

I cannot find the issue with the code below, why I am getting `undefined` for subscription, when an object has been returned that defines the `unsubscribe` method. Ignore `map()` as I just call static `fromTimeout` directly here.

```
class Observable {
  constructor(subscribe) {
    this._subscribe = subscribe
  }
  // Expose public api method for observers to use...
  subscribe(observer) {
    this._subscribe(observer)
  }

  static fromTimeout(time) {
    return new Observable(function(observer) {
      let handler = function() {
        observer.next("next value")
        observer.complete()
      }
      const timeout = setTimeout(handler, time)

      return {
        unsubscribe: function() {
          clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
      }
    })
  }
  map(projection) {
    const self = this

    return new Observable(function(observer) {
      const subscription = self.subscribe({
        next: function(value) {
          observer.next(projection(value))
        },
        complete: function() {
          observer.complete()
        }
      })

      return subscription
    })
  }
}
const obs1 = Observable.fromTimeout(500)

const subscription = obs1
  // .map(v => v.toUpperCase())
  .subscribe({
    next: function(value) {
      console.log("next: ", value)
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log("complete called")
    }
  })

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(subscription) // WHY undefined!?
  subscription.unsubscribe()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Your `.subscribe()` method has no `return` statement. When you can't simply *see* a problem in code, the next thing to do is verify that the things you *think* are true really are, either with a debugging tool or with `console.log()` statements to check the values of variables, parameters, etc. Sometimes the process of thinking about where to put `console.log()` calls will let you see the problem, and sometimes it takes several iterations to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement is missing in:

```
subscribe(observer) {
    return this._subscribe(observer)
}
```

```js
class Observable {
  constructor(subscribe) {
    this._subscribe = subscribe
  }
  // Expose public api method for observers to use...
  subscribe(observer) {
    return this._subscribe(observer)
  }

  static fromTimeout(time) {
    return new Observable(function(observer) {
      let handler = function() {
        observer.next("next value")
        observer.complete()
      }
      const timeout = setTimeout(handler, time)

      return {
        unsubscribe: function() {
          clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
      }
    })
  }
  map(projection) {
    const self = this

    return new Observable(function(observer) {
      const subscription = self.subscribe({
        next: function(value) {
          observer.next(projection(value))
        },
        complete: function() {
          observer.complete()
        }
      })

      return subscription
    })
  }
}
const obs1 = Observable.fromTimeout(500)

const subscription = obs1
  // .map(v => v.toUpperCase())
  .subscribe({
    next: function(value) {
      console.log("next: ", value)
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log("complete called")
    }
  })

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(subscription) // WHY undefined!?
  subscription.unsubscribe()
}, 1000)
```